# running ssh command in the cmd shows me 'Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms'

Tags: ssh, openssh

In the cmd prompt I tried to connect to my server via ssh with following command:
ssh ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

but an error message occured

```
C:\\Users\\jjid/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms
C:\\Users\\jjid/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I checked ssh configuration file and the content,

```
Host yy.yy.yy.yy
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubKeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

If I clear the file, ssh command works.
But I must have that configuration.

How do I fix it?

Comment: It looks you're using the Windows port of OpenSSH; what version? On my up-to-date Win 10 it's 8.1, but the option you ask for only exists in 8.5 up; before that (back to 7.0) it was `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` (case-insensitive) instead. However, [through 8.7 `ssh-rsa` is allowed for hostkey and pubkey by default](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) so you don't need to add it back -- unless you're reusing the same config file for a newer version of OpenSSH, such as one in WSL.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you! I checked the version of SSH using 'ssh -V' command and it was 7.7. So I installed the newest version from 'https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH-Using-MSI', and I removed the old version in "c:\windows\system32\openssh". And now it works!

Answer (score 13):

The SSH version is too low. The option `PubKeyAcceptedAlgorithms` is supported from OpenSSH version 8.5 and above.

An alternative to upgrade is to use the old name `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` as it was simply renamed from version 8.5. [Link to 8.5 release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5)